# Show a countdown and change to another activity when countdown is over.

Tags: java, android, timer

My activity opens another activity after 10 seconds. I know how to open the another activity after some time. But what I want to do is also count every second so I can display it to the user. How can I do that? In my activity I have a textview on which I want to show the count down.

```
public class RestingActivity extends Activity{
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resting);

    mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask, 10000);
}

public void skipRestTime(View view) 
{
    finish();
}


private Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        finish(); // Closing the activity
    }
 };

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check my answer. Its working fine for me. Hope it should helpful for you. Please try and let me know. Thanks

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#0090FF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCountDown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static TextView txtCountDown;
    private static CountDownTimer countDownTimer = null;
        private static final long startTime = 120 * 1000;
        private static final long interval = 1 * 1000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtCountDown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCountDown);
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        if(txtCountDown!=null){
            txtCountDown.setText(String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
        }
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

      public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
          super(startTime, interval);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {
          if(txtCountDown!=null){
            txtCountDown.setText("Time's up!");
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          if(txtCountDown!=null){
            txtCountDown.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried and everything works fine. But when one second is left on the count down it takes much more time to close the activity. It looks like it adds one more second. Do you also have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`CountDownAnimation` class](https://github.com/IvanRF/CountDownAnimation/blob/master/src/com/ivanrf/countdownanimation/CountDownAnimation.java). You only need to pass the `TextView` in which the count down will be shown and set the `CountDownListener`. Then, implement  `onCountDownEnd` to change the activity.

I use a `Handler`, which is much more accurate than `CountDownTimer`. When I implemented `CountDownAnimation`, I made time tests over those classes.